# Should use Head.js or just minified scripts before </body> with scripts in the markup?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, optimization, head.js

I have the optimisation problem — my site uses 2 (pretty large) javascript resources:

1. application.js (minimised jquery, jquery-ui, underscore-js and some shared scripts, 120KB total)
2. controller-specific file (some modules required for the page + interactions, 4KB total)

I have some scripts in the views that format/convert markup with JavaScript (dependable on both jQuery and my controller-specific JS code) so I need to wait either for $(document).ready or head.ready and it makes the part of website invisible to prevent the flash of unstyled content :(

Now my question comes: should I use head.js for it or just stick with the "before " scripts? Are there any smart ways to speed up page loading time in this case?

Update:
Here's the part of the code (see versusio.com for full code, landing page):

```
<html>
  <head>
    ... usual stuff
    <link (css stuff) />
    <script src="head.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Here some global variables are set like cache keys, actual locale code etc., not dependable on jQuery or any other JS code from the JS assets
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    ... page content

    <div id="search">!-- here some code with the "display: none" style to prevent flash of unstyled content</div>
    <script>
      // Here is code that positions and processes some styles and adds some interactions to the #search div
      Application.Position.In.Center($(#search), $(document));
    </script>

    ... more page content

    ... another "display: none" div and accompanying script

    ... rest of the page content

    <script type="text/javascript">head.js( { 'application': 'application.js' }, { 'landing': 'landing.js' } );</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I updated the question with sample code and link to the "full code" :) Thanks for suggestion @Mörre

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ask yourself this question: Do i really need all this javascript loaded when a user visits my page?

When first loading your website, you actually only need the autocomplete-functionality, the rest isn't needed on load. So you could go for a seperated approach. My advice would be the following:

- Build this page without any javascript-functionality and then enhance it with javascript, get rid of the inline styles and scripts.
- After you have done this, load the scripts you actually need, you can do this in the head or just before the end of the body
- Use a CDN for Jquery, jquery-ui, underscore and the other libraries. If a user already loaded these libraries from another website, you have a performance bonus.
- Last of all, already asynchronously load the javascript needed later on, so the user already has the scripts when he hits the compare-button.

Small tweaks:

- Use a tool like ySlow or the networking graph in your favorite browser to look for any bottlenecks. It looks like gzipping is not enabled, try and do that.
- Do you really need to load the facebook/google/twitter/third-party stuff in the head or could that be done when the page is loaded?
- Is the server as fast as possible? It looks like it takes almost halve a second to get the HTML.

I hope i helped you out for a bit, good luck with the performance tweaking!

Comment: Thank you, your answer pushed me into a good direction — I removed head.js, moved scripts just before </body>, added a custom window.load handler and used CDNjs.com CDN :) Now works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, put a load scripts on the bottom of the page (as the last tags in the body). That javascript it will not block the drawing page, like now.

Answer (score 0):

You could put mask layer that cover all pages with fixed style, then hide or destroy it when loading process finished. That way there's no need to hidden each content, instead it will be covered with mask div

Answer (score 0):

Saw the view source of your page.

1. There are some inline scripts which can block rendering. Such as this

> Application.i18n = {"comparisons":{"off_ratio":

More here. http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/deciphering-the-critical-rendering-path/

Quick way: Moving them to the end of body tag.
Best way: They should be loaded as external scripts - with very good cache headers.
May be, you are doing that as - you have to load those messages based on user locale - You can  create separate JS files for every locale during your build process - an they can be linked / loaded as external JS files with good cache headers

Another reason, why you might need inline scripts - to take note of the initial loading time. which is not necessary - as the modern browsers provide us with perfomance timings.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webperformance/basics/

Moving it as an external script file - will also be good for your site security - in case, if you will be trying CSP.

http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/11/Content-Security-Policy-1-0-is-officially-awesome.

1. Defer / async attributes.

ga.js is set with async attibute - but other JS files can be tried with defer attributes. Also, as a general rule of thumb, delay loading resources as far as possible,load only when it is needed.

1. window.onload - $.ready
   Starting your script execution with $.ready is always going to be better than window.onload.
   because, window.onload fires only after all the images, inner iframes gets loaded.

The following links might be useful.

https://developers.google.com/speed/

The Progressive JPEGs post in  http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2012/

http://blog.chriszacharias.com/page-weight-matters

http://www.igvita.com/2013/01/15/faster-websites-crash-course-on-web-performance/

A lot of further optimisations are possible. All the best.

Comment: Thanks for your response — like somebody earlier proposed I moved all non-critical scripts to the end of page, but it turned out $.ready is somehow super slow compared to window.onload and some actions should be performed before $.ready fires (I don't know why is that, but it helped).